# Out of memory only by a matrix transpose

Tags: database, matlab, database-design, signal-processing, octave

I have a cell, `Data`, it contains three *double* arrays,

```
 Data = 

[74003x253 double]    [8061x253 double]    [7241x253 double]
```

I'm using a loop to read these arrays and perform some functions,

```
for ii = 1 : 3
    D = Data {ii} ;
    m = mean (D') ;
    // rest of the code
end
```

Which gets a warning for `mean` and says:

*consider using different DIMENSION input argument for MEAN*

However when I change it to,

```
for ii = 1 : 3
    D = Data {ii}' ;
    m = mean (D) ;
    // rest of the code
end
```

I get *Out of memory error*.

Comparing two codes, can someone explain what happens?

It seems that I get the error only with a *Complex conjugate transpose* (my data is real valued).

Comment: On which iteration does _Out of memory error_ occur? Can you tell the value of `ii` before failure?

Comment: @user502144, Actually, _out of memory error_ doesn't mention the line (I had made a mistake to mention it for the error, which I corrected). However, with the only a transpose change in these two codes I can make the error go away.

Comment: For one `'` has nothing to do with complex numbers - it transposes matrices which also means it needs to make a copy (needs extra ram). My guess is, since Matlab uses a very advanced just in time compiler, it recognizes the first cases and correctly replaces it with `mean(D,2)`.

Comment: @bdecaf `'` is not the same as transpose `.'`. The operator `'` is actually the [hermitian (complex) transpose](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html).

Comment: @huntj, as I've mentioned my data is real valued.

Comment: @huntj I admit I wasn't aware of the fine difference. But I assume the compiler will correctly simplify it for real numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To take the mean for the n:th dimension it is possible use `mean(D,n)` as already stated. Regarding the memory consumption, I did some tests monitoring with the windows resource manager. The output was kind of expected.

When doing the operation `D=Data{ii}` only minimum memory is consumed since here matlab does no more than copying a pointer. However, when doing a transpose, matlab needs to allocate more memory to store the matrix D, which means that the memory consumption increases.

However, this solely does not cause a memory overflow, since the transpose is done in both cases.

**Case 1**

Separately in`D = Data{ii}';`

**Case 2**

in 
`D = Data {ii}; m = mean(D');`

The difference is that in **case 2** matlab only creates a temporary copy of `Data{ii}'` which is not stored in the workspace. The memory allocated is the same in both cases, but in **case 1** `Data{ii}'` is stored in `D`. When the memory later increases this can cause a memory overflow.

The memory consumption of `D` is not that bad (< 200 Mb), but the guess is that the memory got high already and that this was enough to give memory overflow.

Answer (score 6):

The warning message means that instead of,

```
m = mean (D') ;
```

you should do:

```
m = mean (D,2);
```

This will take the mean along the second dimension, leaving you with a column vector the length of `size(D,1)`.

I don't know why you only get the out of memory error when you do `D = Data {ii}'`.  Perhaps it's becauase when you have it in side of `mean` (`m = mean (D') ;` the JIT manages to optimize somehow and save you wasted memory.

Comment: I didn't know about `mean(D,2)`, Thanks. And for the memory error, it's really strange.

Comment: @Kamtal: Whenever reading MATLAB documentation, the phrase "... operates on the first non-singleton dimension" means that the operation is a ["reduction, or fold, or multi-input single-output operator"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), and that the operator will group together elements taken from the "first non-singleton dimension".

Comment: If I had to guess, `D=Data{i}'` actually creates a full transposed copy of the data before passing it to `mean(D)`. On the other hand, `D=Data{i}` first creates a shared-data copy (think lazy copy-on-write), then the call `mean(D')` is passed a "temporary" expression, which is a possible target for JIT optimization (by recognizing that `mean` can compute the result without actually transposing the matrix in a new copy, it suffices to traverse the existing matrix in strides of appropriate length)

Comment: @Amro Well stated, that's what I was thinking regarding JIT compilation -- the ability to compute it along the other dimension based on the clue it gets from `'` without actually transposing any data.  But can this be proven/demonstrated?  I don't think there's a good way that wouldn't possibly influence JIT optimization (like debugging would certainly do). Anyway, I'm skeptical because `mean` is not a built-in.

Comment: @chappjc: best I can think of is to create an example with sufficiently large matrices, and run MATLAB under a profiler that tracks memory allocations to see if a copy of the data is ever made in each case.. I used this technique [in another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26346590/97160) using Intel VTune Amplifier to watch number of threads spawned (but not memory allocated)

Comment: @Amro My Composer XE trial is expired and I'm not sure if VS gives much memory info.  I'd suggest the OP try since I can't reproduce the issue right now and I'm not eager to start my system memory paging out.  :)

Comment: @chappjc: if I remember correctly the existing MATLAB profiler has some undocumented option to track memory allocations.. Although like you said, running under the profiler might disable certain optimizations. Anyways I dont think one should worry about such implementation details, especially since the behavior can change from version to version...

Comment: @Amro Yes, prior to R2008b there was the `mtic`/`mtoc` set, and more recently you could do [`profile -memory on`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-profiler-options), which might still work. Snipe hunt!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways of doing this:

```
for i = 1 : length(Data)
   % as chappjc recommends this is an excellent solution
   m = mean(Data{i}, 2);
end
```

Or if you want the transpose and you know the data is real (not complex)

```
for i = 1 : length(Data)
   m = mean(Data{i}.');
end
```

Note, the dot before the transpose.

Or, skip the loop all together

```
m = cellfun(@(d) mean(d, 2), Data, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

When you do:

```
D = Data{i}'
```

Matlab will create a new copy of your data. This will allocate 74003x253 doubles, which is about 150MB. As patrick pointed out, given that you might have other data you can easily exceed the allowed memory allocation usage (especially on a 32-bit machine).

If you are running with memory problems, the computations are not sensitive, you may consider using single precision instead of double, i.e.:

```
data{i} = single(data{i});
```

Ideally, you want to do the single precision at point of allocation to avoid unnecessary new allocation and copies.

Good luck.